# Pegar sistema operacional do servidor em PHP

Tags: php, servidor

Como posso pegar o sistema operacional do servidor no PHP?
Gostaria de retornar algo semelhante assim:

```
Windows 7 Service Pack 1 x64
```

Answer (score 3):

De uma olhada na função e verifique se é o que você está precisando.

```
php_uname('s')
php_uname('m')
php_uname('v')
```

[Php-uname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)